# mv command not working from bash script php

Tags: php, linux, bash

I am running the following code to run bash commands

```
shell_exec("sudo sh script.sh $conf_file");
```

The `$config_file` holds the value of e.g `abc.conf`

In my script.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
mv $1 /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

I have also given permission to www-data user to use sudo without password by going to `sudo visudo` and added the following line in last

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/myapp/script.sh
```

Comment: note you are giving permissions to perform the action `/var/www/html/myapp/script.sh`, whereas you are running `sh script.sh`.

Comment: so i am calling that php code within the same directory. it is eventually the same path ?

Comment: It is the same path, but sudoers checks exact strings, so you have to write the full path.

Comment: so if i write only `script.sh` in visudo then it will work ?

Comment: i tried enter full path in my shell_exec command but its not even executing simple whoami command now

Comment: First of all you should make sure that `www-data` is able to run the command from the command line, so you are sure the sudoers is well defined. When it is, then see how to implement it in your php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `sh` by sudo, not `/var/www/html/myapp/script.sh` one. It's also strange why you are runing `script.sh` by `sh` when your script begins with line `#!/bin/bash`. Simply try to change `shell_exec` to:

```
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/myapp/script.sh $conf_file");
```

Comment: Full path (or at least relative one) is likely necessary here both for `sudo` and for the script to actually be found.

Comment: Does your script have the execute bit set?

Comment: I don't know about this can you please tell me how to set or any link ?

Comment: i did try with doing chmod +x myscript.sh but `shell_exec` not working if i remove `sh` from it

Comment: finally command working without sh but if i prepend sudo with it it doesn't work `echo shell_exec("/var/www/html/myapp/script.sh $conf_file")`;